# Error: File format not recognized

Tags: hyperlink, linker, makefile, g++, raspberry-pi2

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 running Ubuntu MATE 15.10 to work on a project.
I'm trying to run a makefile and got this error

```
/home/dpanagou/Quadrotors/Vicon/libs/libViconDataStreamSDK_CPP.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:8: recipe for target '../bin/Vicon_state' failed
make[1]: *** [../bin/Vicon_state] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dpanagou/Quadrotors/HLP/Vicon'
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'Vicon' failed
make: *** [Vicon] Error 2
```

I've also tried `make clean` before `make`.
From research, a lot of people have suggested that the object file might be corrupted. So I downloaded new files from the developer and ran the makefile again. I still get the same error.

Here is my makefile:

```
CUR_DIR = $(shell pwd)
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags lcm`
LDFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs lcm` ../src/filter_util.o ../src/util.o

vicon_lib = $(CUR_DIR:%/HLP/Vicon=%/Vicon/libs)

../bin/Vicon_state:
g++ $(CFLAGS) Vicon_state_data.cpp -o ../bin/Vicon_state -Wl,-  rpath=../../Vicon/libs -L$(vicon_lib) -lViconDataStreamSDK_CPP -lDebugServices $(LDFLAGS)
```

Please help with specific instructions as I am very new to Linux and programming.

Comment: Please dont provide a image of your error but post it in your question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the format of the file with the "file" command, and compare it to the format of any .so that comes with rpi.

I'm not 100% sure, but  might it be that the library is for raspbian with its v6 compatible HF vs generic V7-only HF in debian?

Comment: This is what it returned when I check using the `file` command:  `libViconDataStreamSDK_CPP.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=38d8dcc120ec023fb3cd074d221dd551d6b311ef, not stripped`

Comment: I checked with another .so file that comes with rpi and this is what it returned: `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libloglo.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=ca546a655f47df2efc97742f492f968c9cb5e9ed, stripped`

Comment: livicondatastreamsdk*  is a x86_64 library, iow for Intel PCs, not for ARM RPIs. This is never going to work this way.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer or point me to a website I can read more about this? I'm new to software development.

Comment: You could look up architecture (software) or so on wikipedia. Sufficient to say is that libraries are for a specific processor, and you can't simply copy them to use on other CPUs. You need to recompile the library for your system.

Comment: Is there any way I can cross-compile these files for the ARM RPIs? If not, how do I go about recompiling the library for my system? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, but that requires some work. afaik there are no ready to make point and do solutions.